# PatIndex Pattern /Regex: How to match a dot followed by a space

Tags: sql-server, regex, patindex

Q1-PatIndex Pattern Regex: How to match a dot followed by a space? 
Q2 -PatIndex Pattern Regex: How to match a dot followed by two spaces?.

I want to put it in here to get only the GOAL content

```
 Declare @Temp Table(Data VarChar(1000))

Insert Into @Temp Values('Lalallaa GOAL: This is the truthmeow. Meow.  ')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Lalallaa GOAL: This is the truth. Meowrwr. ')
Insert Into @Temp Values('lALALLA GOAL: This is the truth. Meowrwr.  NOTINCLUDED: WAWAW')


Select Left(
             SubString(Data,PATINDEX ('%GOAL%',Data), 8000) ,
             PatIndex('regex here', SubString(Data, PatIndex('%[GOAL]%', Data), 8000))-1)
From   @Temp
```

Expected Output

```
GOAL: This is the truthmeow. 
GOAL: This is the truth.
GOAL: This is the truth.
```

I used Shnugos answer on the real DB and I encountered an error : `Illegal name character`

I checked the data type , it is `ntext`

Comment: `\.\s` (Q1) or `\.\s{2}` (Q2). Roger and out :)

Comment: There are tons of tutorials and online test forms out there in the great wild world. SO is not a homework platform...

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: updated question @RahulTripathi

Comment: @PhilipMorris:- Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Now I'll remove my down vote as this is a "normal" question now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

Short explanation: Replacing `.` with xml-tags will "split" this string in as many "parts" as there are in your string. The XML-value method will take the first item's value which is the string up to the first `.`

```
Declare @Temp Table(Data VarChar(1000))

Insert Into @Temp Values('Lalallaa GOAL: This is the truthmeow. Meow.  ')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Lalallaa GOAL: This is the truth. Meowrwr. ')
Insert Into @Temp Values('lALALLA GOAL: This is the truth. Meowrwr. NOTINCLUDED: WAWAW')


Select CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(SubString(Data,PATINDEX ('%GOAL%',Data), 8000),'. ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('x[1]','varchar(max)')
From   @Temp
```

Comment: I got Lalallaa GOAL: This is the truthmeow, Lalallaa GOAL: This is the truth, lALALLA GOAL: This is the truth

Comment: @PhilipMorris, that's easy, just use your own `substring` approach to cut off the beginning, edited my answer...

Comment: any chance it wont work with chinese characters or special characters? Im getting an error  XML parsing: Illegal name character

Comment: @PhilipMorris You probably must declare all your variable as **N**VARCHAR and put an "N" to all literally written strings (`N'Your string here'`) to make it unicode...

Comment: I confirmed and the type is ntext

Comment: @PhilipMorris NTEXT is depricated, you might cast it to NVARCHAR(MAX). Btw: I answered your question **as it was written**. There was nothing mentioned about special characters. The right thing on SO is to close one question (with votes on all good or bad contributions and an accept) and than start a new question with the new problem. [Please read this, especially the point about *taking away the acceptance*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/5089204)

Comment: @PhilipMorris Thx :-) If you place a follow-up question it is a good idea to place a link (from the "share" option below your question) as a comment here (or include a link into your new question) I'll be happy to pop up there and help you if needed...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the LIKE statement as well.

```
columnname LIKE '.  %'
```

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
Select SUBSTRING(data, LEN(LEFT(data, CHARINDEX ('GOAL:', data))) , LEN(data) - LEN(LEFT(data, CHARINDEX ('GOAL:', data))) - LEN(RIGHT(data, LEN(data) - CHARINDEX ('.', data))) - 1)
From   @Temp
```

Comment: I got GOAL: This is the truthmeow., GOAL: This is the truth , GOAL: This is the trut